# Swift Error- keyNotFound(CodingKeys(stringValue:, intValue: nil), Swift.DecodingError.Context,

Tags: ios, swift, uikit, codable

I am trying to read off Connecticut coronavirus data from this API JSON File- "https://data.ct.gov/resource/rf3k-f8fg.json"  ( but I'm getting this error from excode that says keyNotFound(CodingKeys(stringValue: "covid19TestsReported", intValue: nil), Swift.DecodingError.Context

However this error, only comes up when I try to access the covid_19_tests_reported property of the file.

Here is my code, can someone please tell me what I'm doing wrong.

```
import UIKit


class StateViewController: UIViewController {


@IBOutlet weak var testRatioLbl: UILabel!



override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    getData()

}

fileprivate func getData(){

    let url = URL(string: "https://data.ct.gov/resource/rf3k-f8fg.json")!
    URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url){(data, response, error) in

        do {
            let decoder = JSONDecoder()
            decoder.keyDecodingStrategy = .convertFromSnakeCase
            let users = try decoder.decode([Users].self, from: data!)
            print(users)





        }
        catch {

            print(error)
        }


    }.resume()
}

  func didUpdatePrice(tests: String) {


    DispatchQueue.main.async {
    self.testRatioLbl.text = tests + " tests"

    }
}

func didFailWithError(error: Error) {
    print(error)
}

    }

    class Users: Decodable {

let covid19TestsReported: String
enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
    case covid19TestsReported = "covid19TestsReported"

}
required init(from decoder:Decoder) throws {
    let values = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
    covid19TestsReported = try values.decode(String.self, forKey: .covid19TestsReported)
}
```

}

Comment: Could you print the JSON?

Comment: I was able to print various aspects of the JSON but not the whole JSON or the tests part for some reason

Answer (score 3, accepted):

update you class.. your key value is "`covid_19_tests_reported`" not "`covid19TestsReported`"

because this field is nil in some cases so make it optional

```
 struct Users: Decodable {
    let covid19TestsReported: String?

  private  enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case covid19TestsReported = "covid_19_tests_reported"

    }
}
```

Also update your getData

```
 fileprivate func getData(){

        let url = URL(string: "https://data.ct.gov/resource/rf3k-f8fg.json")!
        URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url){(data, response, error) in

            do {
                let decoder = JSONDecoder()
                let users = try decoder.decode([Users].self, from: data!)

                users.forEach { (user) in
                    if let cases = user.covid19TestsReported {
                    print(cases)
                    }
                }
            }
            catch {

                print(error)
            }


        }.resume()
    }
```

Comment: Um, that doesn't seem to work, I still get the following error:     Also, by the way, the reason that I put covid19TestsReported as my key value is because I found on the internet that one of the problems might be that I needed to convert the key to snake case. Another question I had was if I should get rid of the "init from"

Comment: i updated my answer .. try it now please and let me know

Comment: This is my error: keyNotFound(CodingKeys(stringValue: "covid_19_tests_reported", intValue: nil), Swift.DecodingError.Context(codingPath: [_JSONKey(stringValue: "Index 0", intValue: 0)], debugDescription: "No value associated with key CodingKeys(stringValue: \"covid_19_tests_reported\", intValue: nil) (\"covid_19_tests_reported\").", underlyingError: nil))

Comment: I dont see your updated answer- it appears to be the same and gives me that same error, where is your updated answer

Comment: make it optional ... `Int?` instead of `Int`

Comment: ok, I have tried the updated answer, and it runs with no error, but it still doesn't solve my initial problem, because for some reason this covid_19_tests_reported is assigned with the value nil. Do you know why this is?

Comment: basicially what Im trying to do is get the number covid_19_tests_reported from https://data.ct.gov/resource/rf3k-f8fg.json, and as you can see it displays 142943 on that JSON, but it displays nil when it comes out

Comment: Please let me know if you know where I am going wrong.

Comment: now i tested the code ... please use updated user struct