# Running into the Error: keyNotFound, DecodingError when trying to fetch messages from Firebase Database

Tags: swift, firebase, swiftui

I get this Error:

```
keyNotFound(CodingKeys(stringValue: "email", intValue: nil), 
Swift.DecodingError.Context(codingPath: [], debugDescription: "No value associated with
key CodingKeys(stringValue: \"email\", intValue: nil) (\"email\").", underlyingError: nil))
```

I am not sure what this Error is trying to tell me, I read through this question: [Swift Error- keyNotFound(CodingKeys(stringValue:, intValue: nil), Swift.DecodingError.Context,](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61798393/swift-error-keynotfoundcodingkeysstringvalue-intvalue-nil-swift-decoding) which has the same Error. Though I couldn't figure out how to change my ChatUser so that my App works.
Trying to fetch messages from my Firestore database.
I tried debugging and I am pretty sure
`ForEach(vm.recentMessages) { recentMessage in }`  leads to the error.

This is my ViewModel:

```
class MessagesViewModel: ObservableObject {
    
    @Published var errorMessage = ""
    @Published var chatUser: ChatUser?

    init() {
        fetchCurrentUser()
        fetchRecentMessages()
    }
    @Published var recentMessages = [RecentMessage]()
    
    private var firestoreListener: ListenerRegistration?
    
   func fetchRecentMessages() {
        guard let uid = FirebaseManager.shared.auth.currentUser?.uid else { return }
        
        firestoreListener?.remove()
        self.recentMessages.removeAll()
        
        firestoreListener = FirebaseManager.shared.firestore
            .collection(FirebaseConstants.recentMessages)
            .document(uid)
            .collection(FirebaseConstants.messages)
            .order(by: FirebaseConstants.timestamp)
            .addSnapshotListener { querySnapshot, error in
                if let error = error {
                    self.errorMessage = "Failed to listen for recent messages: \(error)"
                    print(error)
                    return
                }
                
                querySnapshot?.documentChanges.forEach({ change in
                    let docId = change.document.documentID
                    
                    if let index = self.recentMessages.firstIndex(where: { rm in
                        return rm.id == docId
                    }) {
                        self.recentMessages.remove(at: index)
                    }
                    
                    do {
                         let rm = try change.document.data(as: RecentMessage.self)
                            self.recentMessages.insert(rm, at: 0)
                    } catch {
                        print(error)
                    }
                })
            }
}
    func fetchCurrentUser() {
        guard let uid = FirebaseManager.shared.auth.currentUser?.uid else {
            self.errorMessage = "Could not find firebase uid"
            return
        }
        
        FirebaseManager.shared.firestore.collection("users").document(uid).getDocument { snapshot, error in
            if let error = error {
                self.errorMessage = "Failed to fetch current user: \(error)"
                print("Failed to fetch current user:", error)
                return
            }
            
            self.chatUser = try? snapshot?.data(as: ChatUser.self)
            FirebaseManager.shared.currentUser = self.chatUser
        }
    }
        
        FirebaseManager.shared.firestore.collection("users").document(uid).getDocument { snapshot, error in
            if let error = error {
                self.errorMessage = "Failed to fetch current user: \(error)"
                print("Failed to fetch current user:", error)
                return
            }
            
            self.chatUser = try? snapshot?.data(as: ChatUser.self)
            FirebaseManager.shared.currentUser = self.chatUser
        }
    }
}
```

This is the View the messages should appear in:

```
struct MessagesView: View {
    @ObservedObject private var vm = MessagesViewModel()
    private var chatLogViewModel = ChatLogViewModel(chatUser: FirebaseManager.shared.currentUser)
    @State var chatUser: ChatUser?

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            HStack {
                Button() {
                    
                } label: {
                    Image("search").resizable()
                        .frame(width: 32, height: 32)
                        .padding(.leading, 11)
                }
                Spacer()
                    Image("AppIcon").resizable()
                        .frame(width: 32, height: 32)
                        .scaledToFill()
                Spacer()
                Button() {
                } label: {
                    Image("dots").resizable()
                        .renderingMode(.template)
                        .frame(width: 32, height: 32)
                        .foregroundColor(Color(.init(red: 0.59, green: 0.62, blue: 0.67, alpha: 1)))
                        .padding(.trailing, 9)
                        .offset(y: -4)
                }
            }.padding(.init(top: 0, leading: 8, bottom: 0, trailing: 8))
            NavigationView {
                VStack {
                    messagesView
                }
            }
        }
    }
    
    private var messagesView: some View {
        ScrollView {
            ForEach(vm.recentMessages) { recentMessage in
                VStack {
                    Button {
                        let uid = FirebaseManager.shared.auth.currentUser?.uid == recentMessage.fromId ? recentMessage.toId : recentMessage.fromId
                        
                        self.chatUser = .init(id: uid, uid: uid, email: recentMessage.email, profileImageUrl: recentMessage.profileImageUrl)
                        
                        self.chatLogViewModel.chatUser = self.chatUser
                        self.chatLogViewModel.fetchMessages()
                    } label: {
                        HStack(spacing: 16) {
                            WebImage(url: URL(string: recentMessage.profileImageUrl))
                                .resizable()
                                .scaledToFill()
                                .frame(width: 64, height: 64)
                                .clipped()
                                .cornerRadius(64)
                                .overlay(RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 64)
                                            .stroke(Color.black, lineWidth: 1))
                                .shadow(radius: 5)
                            
                            
                            VStack(alignment: .leading, spacing: 8) {
                                Text(recentMessage.username)
                                    .font(.system(size: 16, weight: .bold))
                                    .foregroundColor(Color(.label))
                                    .multilineTextAlignment(.leading)
                                Text(recentMessage.text)
                                    .font(.system(size: 14))
                                    .foregroundColor(Color(.darkGray))
                                    .multilineTextAlignment(.leading)
                            }
                            Spacer()
                            
                            Text(recentMessage.timeAgo)
                                .font(.system(size: 14, weight: .semibold))
                                .foregroundColor(Color(.label))
                        }
                    }


                    
                    Divider()
                        .padding(.vertical, 8)
                }.padding(.horizontal)
            }.padding(.bottom, 50)
        }
    }
    
}
```

ChatUser looks like this:

```
import FirebaseFirestoreSwift

struct ChatUser: Codable, Identifiable {
    @DocumentID var id: String?
    let uid, email, profileImageUrl: String
}
```

```
struct RecentMessage: Codable, Identifiable {
    
    @DocumentID var id: String?
    let text, email: String
    let fromId, toId: String
    let profileImageUrl: String
    let timestamp: Date
    
    var username: String {
        email.components(separatedBy: "@").first ?? email
    }
    
    var timeAgo: String {
        let formatter = RelativeDateTimeFormatter()
        formatter.unitsStyle = .abbreviated
        return formatter.localizedString(for: timestamp, relativeTo: Date())
    }
}
```

Comment: If you check the Firestore console, is there a document (ChatUser) in the collection „users“ without the field email? For me it seems you get from Firestore an item without email (nil) but your struct is expecting a String. Did you inspect what you receive from Firestore with the debugger?

Comment: The chatuser is nil but I don't know why.. Everything in my database is fine

Comment: According to the code both `func fetchRecentMessages()`and `func fetchCurrentUser()` are empty, note  the pair of braces. Does the code compile?

Comment: My bad i forgot to put them in. I just edited it.

Comment: I don't know whether it helps or not but I get the Error logged twice.

Comment: Are you aware that `fetchCurrentUser` works asynchronously? At the moment `fetchRecentMessages` is called in the init method the chat user is still `nil`

Comment: So I need to call them in my View again?

Answer (score 1):

## Update

I made some adjustments and added the RecentMessage portion. Now it works entirely for me. I can get the current (ChatUser) from Firestore and I also can get the RecentMessages. Now it loads all RecentMessages, this should be changes to ones that are in relationship with the current user.

## Models

#### ChatUser

```
import Foundation
import SwiftUI
import Firebase

struct ChatUser: Codable, Identifiable, Hashable {
    
    var id: String?
    var email: String
    var profileImageUrl: String
    var uid: String
   
    
    init(email: String, profileImageUrl: String, uid: String, id: String?) {
        self.id = id
        self.email = email
        self.profileImageUrl = profileImageUrl
        self.uid = uid

    }
    
    init?(document: DocumentSnapshot) {
        let data = document.data()
        
        let email = data!["email"] as? String ?? ""
        let profileImageUrl = data!["profileImageUrl"] as? String ?? ""
        let uid = data!["uid"] as? String ?? ""
        
        id = document.documentID
        self.email = email
        self.profileImageUrl = profileImageUrl
        self.uid = uid
    }
    
    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case id
        case email
        case profileImageUrl
        case uid
    }
}

extension ChatUser: Comparable {
    
    static func == (lhs: ChatUser, rhs: ChatUser) -> Bool {
        return lhs.id == rhs.id
    }
    
    static func < (lhs: ChatUser, rhs: ChatUser) -> Bool {
        return lhs.email < rhs.email
    }
}
```

#### RecentMessage

```
struct RecentMessage: Codable, Identifiable, Hashable {
    
    var id: String?
    var text: String
    var email: String
    var fromId: String
    var toId: String
    var profileImageUrl: String
    var timestamp: Date
    
    init(text: String, email: String, fromId: String, toId: String, profileImageUrl: String, timestamp: Date, id: String?) {
        self.id = id
        self.text = text
        self.email = email
        self.fromId = email
        self.toId = email
        self.profileImageUrl = profileImageUrl
        self.timestamp = timestamp
        
    }
    
    init?(document: DocumentSnapshot) {
        let data = document.data()
        
        let text = data!["text"] as? String ?? ""
        let email = data!["email"] as? String ?? ""
        let fromId = data!["fromId"] as? String ?? ""
        let toId = data!["toId"] as? String ?? ""
        let profileImageUrl = data!["profileImageUrl"] as? String ?? ""
        let timestamp = data!["timestamp"] as? Date ?? Date()
        
        id = document.documentID
        self.text = text
        self.email = email
        self.fromId = fromId
        self.toId = toId
        self.profileImageUrl = profileImageUrl
        self.timestamp = timestamp
    }
    
    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case id
        case text
        case email
        case fromId
        case toId
        case profileImageUrl
        case timestamp
    }


    func getUsernameFromEmail() -> String {
        return email.components(separatedBy: "@").first ?? email
    }

    func getElapsedTime() -> String  {
        let formatter = RelativeDateTimeFormatter()
        formatter.unitsStyle = .abbreviated
        return formatter.localizedString(for: timestamp, relativeTo: Date())
    }
}

extension RecentMessage: Comparable {
    
    static func == (lhs: RecentMessage, rhs: RecentMessage) -> Bool {
        return lhs.id == rhs.id
    }
    
    static func < (lhs: RecentMessage, rhs: RecentMessage) -> Bool {
        return lhs.timestamp < rhs.timestamp
    }
}
```

## ViewModels

One thing in advance, instead of using FirebaseManager.shared, I declared once in the ViewModel:

```
let db = Firestore.firestore()
```

I split the existing MessagesViewModel into MessagesViewModel and UserViewModel

I added a completion block to the fetchCurrentUser function.
It must be completed first (successfully) to run the fetchRecentMessage function. With that block we do 2 things:

1. make sure the fetchCurrentUser function is completed. I assume, even if the id is saved to the database, in your init function the fetchRecentMessage function will be called before you got the data for the currentUser. It is asynchronous and your code is not waiting for Firestore to be finished.
2. make sure that chatUser really is initialized with the values from Firestore.

#### UserViewModel

```
class UsersViewModel: ObservableObject {
    
    let db = Firestore.firestore()
    
    @Published var errorMessage = ""
    @Published var chatUser: ChatUser?
    
    func fetchCurrentUser(_ completion: @escaping (Bool, String) ->Void) {
        guard let uid = Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid else {
            self.errorMessage = "Could not find firebase uid"
            completion(false, self.errorMessage)
            return
        }
        
        let docRef = self.db.collection("chatUsers").document(uid)
        docRef.getDocument { (document, error) in
            if let document = document, document.exists {
                self.chatUser = ChatUser(document: document)
                completion(true, "ChatUser set up from Firestore db")
            } else {
                self.errorMessage = "ChatUser document not found"
                completion(false, self.errorMessage)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

#### MessagesViewModel

```
class MessagesViewModel: ObservableObject {
    
    let db = Firestore.firestore()
    
    @Published var errorMessage = ""
    
    @Published var recentMessages: [RecentMessage] = []
    private var firestoreListener: ListenerRegistration?
    
    func fetchData(_ completion: @escaping (Bool, String) ->Void) {
        self.recentMessages.removeAll()
        db.collection("recentMessages").addSnapshotListener { (querySnapshot, error) in
            guard let documents = querySnapshot?.documents else {
                self.errorMessage = "No documents"
                completion(true, self.errorMessage)
                return
            }
            
            self.recentMessages = documents.map { queryDocumentSnapshot -> RecentMessage in
                return RecentMessage(document: queryDocumentSnapshot)!
            }
            completion(true, "Data fetched")
        }
    }
}
```

## Views

#### ContentView

The ContentView just opens the next view ***MusicBandFanView()***, when the MusicBandFanView() appears it first calls the ***fetchCurrentUser()*** function and when the completion block of that function is completed, it calls the ***fetchRecentMessages()*** function

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @Environment(\.managedObjectContext) private var viewContext
    @EnvironmentObject var usersViewModel: UsersViewModel
    @EnvironmentObject var messagesViewModel: MessagesViewModel
    @EnvironmentObject var authViewModel: AuthViewModel
    
    var body: some View {
        MusicBandFanView()
            .onAppear {
                usersViewModel.fetchCurrentUser({ (success, logMessage) -> Void in
                    if success {
                        print(logMessage)
                        messagesViewModel.fetchData({ (success, logMessage) -> Void in
                            print(logMessage)
                        })
                        
                    } else {
                        print(logMessage)
                    }
                })
            }
    }
}
```

#### MusicBandFanView

This is the first part of your view. I just change the messageView from a var within the MusicBandFanView to a distinct view.
Since I don't have your images you use, I used SF-Symbols instead.

```
struct MusicBandFanView: View {
    @Environment(\.managedObjectContext) private var viewContext
    @EnvironmentObject var usersViewModel: UsersViewModel
    @EnvironmentObject var messagesViewModel: MessagesViewModel
    @EnvironmentObject var authViewModel: AuthViewModel
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack() {
            
            HStack {
                Button() {
                    
                } label: {
                    Image(systemName: "magnifyingglass")
                        .frame(width: 32, height: 32)
                        .padding(.leading, 11)
                }
                Spacer()
                Image(systemName: "applelogo")
                    .frame(width: 32, height: 32)
                    .scaledToFill()
                Spacer()
                Button() {
                } label: {
                    Image(systemName: "ellipsis")
                        .renderingMode(.template)
                        .frame(width: 32, height: 32)
                        .foregroundColor(Color(.init(red: 0.59, green: 0.62, blue: 0.67, alpha: 1)))
                        .padding(.trailing, 9)
                        .offset(y: -4)
                }
            }.padding(.init(top: 0, leading: 8, bottom: 0, trailing: 8))
            
            NavigationView {
                VStack {
                    Text("messages")
                    MessagesView()
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

#### MessagesView

That is what you put into a var.
I don't really got what you tried with the button, but I guess you can add that portion similar to the exiting code.
Since I didn't install SDWebimages for the test environment here, I just used an alternative SF-Symbol.

```
struct MessagesView: View {
    @Environment(\.managedObjectContext) private var viewContext
    @EnvironmentObject var usersViewModel: UsersViewModel
    @EnvironmentObject var messagesViewModel: MessagesViewModel
    @EnvironmentObject var authViewModel: AuthViewModel
    
    var body: some View {
        ScrollView {
            VStack {
                ForEach(messagesViewModel.recentMessages, id: \.self){ recentMessage in
                    Button {
                        // I don't really get what you try to do here. The user is already logged in and the fetch for the chatUser (current user) has already been performed.
                    } label: {
                        HStack(spacing: 16) {
                            
                            Image(systemName: "person.crop.circle.fill")
                                .resizable()
                                .scaledToFill()
                                .frame(width: 64, height: 64)
                                .clipShape(Circle())
                                .overlay(Circle()
                                    .stroke(Color.black, lineWidth: 1))
                                .shadow(radius: 5)
                            
                            VStack(alignment: .leading, spacing: 8) {
                                Text(recentMessage.getUsernameFromEmail())
                                    .font(.system(size: 16, weight: .bold))
                                    .foregroundColor(Color(.label))
                                    .multilineTextAlignment(.leading)
                                Text(recentMessage.text)
                                    .font(.system(size: 14))
                                    .foregroundColor(Color(.darkGray))
                                    .multilineTextAlignment(.leading)
                            }
                            
                            Spacer()
                            
                            Text("\(recentMessage.getElapsedTime())")
                                .font(.system(size: 14, weight: .semibold))
                                .foregroundColor(Color(.label))
                        }
                    }
                    
                    Divider()
                        .padding(.vertical, 8)
                    
                }
                .padding(.horizontal)
            }
            .padding(.bottom, 50)
        }
    }
}
```

### Screenshots

#### App Screenshot from simulator

[image: App Screenshot from simulator]

#### Firestore Console Output ChatUser

[image: Firestore Console Output]

#### Firestore Console Output RecentMessage

[image: Firestore Console Output RecentMessage]

Comment: Tried it out but this still results in the same Error. Probably something is wrong with my RecentMessage

Comment: What happens if you comment out **fetchRecentMessages()**, so you just run the fetchCurrentUser function? Does it still fail even you are not getting in touch with **RecentMessage**? One more thing: In your Firestore ChatUser document, are the **id** and the **uid** identical? In your request you are asking for the document ***uid***, so the document id must be the uid. In my screenshot of Firestore you can see the document id in *chatUsers* is identical to the value in the **uid** field.

Comment: They're the same values. If I comment out fetchRecentMessages the Error disappears

Comment: But I don't save the id in my database

Comment: Due to your latest comments, I assume the issue is, you call the fetchRecentMessages function while chatUser is still not initialized. The should be the id issue, but I guess it would still fail with the correctly saved id. Since getting data from Firestore is asynchronous, you (most-likely) call the fetchRecentMessages func before you get back the data from Firestore. I updated the code in the answer and added a completion block to your fetchCurrentUser function. After completion and successfully initializing the chatUser the fetchRecentMessages function will be called.

Comment: Even with the completionblock I still get the error, self.chatUser is nil but the vm.chatUser has a value. I never get into this code `self.chatUser = .init(email: recentMessage.email, profileImageUrl: recentMessage.profileImageUrl, uid: uid, id: recentMessage.id)`

Comment: [Screenshot of output](https://imgur.com/a/yOv2AVj)

Comment: I updated the answer to something that worked for me entirely (in that scope).

Comment: Thanks! I'll look into it, it's easier to comprehend where what gets called and at what place in code